# Very good validation accuracy but bad predictions

Tags: keras, conv-neural-network

I'm building a keras model to classify cats and dogs. I used transfer learning with bottleneck features and fine tuning with vgg model. Now I get very good validation accuracy like 97% but when I get to predict I get very bad results regarding the classification report and confusion matrix. What could be the problem?

Here is the code of fine tuning and the results I get

```
base_model = applications.VGG16(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_shape=(150,150,3))
print('Model loaded.')

# build a classifier model to put on top of the convolutional model
top_model = Sequential()
top_model.add(Flatten(input_shape=base_model.output_shape[1:]))
top_model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))
top_model.add(Dropout(0.5))
top_model.add(Dense(2, activation='sigmoid'))

# note that it is necessary to start with a fully-trained
# classifier, including the top classifier,
# in order to successfully do fine-tuning
top_model.load_weights(top_model_weights_path)

# add the model on top of the convolutional base
# model.add(top_model)
model = Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=top_model(base_model.output))

# set the first 25 layers (up to the last conv block)
# to non-trainable (weights will not be updated)
for layer in model.layers[:15]:
    layer.trainable = False

# compile the model with a SGD/momentum optimizer
# and a very slow learning rate.
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer=optimizers.SGD(lr=1e-4, momentum=0.9),
              metrics=['accuracy'])

# prepare data augmentation configuration
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1. / 255,
    shear_range=0.2,
    zoom_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True)

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    train_data_dir,
    target_size=(img_height, img_width),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='categorical')

validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    validation_data_dir,
    target_size=(img_height, img_width),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='categorical')

model.summary()

# fine-tune the model
model.fit_generator(
    train_generator,
    steps_per_epoch=nb_train_samples // batch_size,
    epochs=epochs,
    validation_data=validation_generator,
    validation_steps=nb_validation_samples // batch_size,
    verbose=2)
scores=model.evaluate_generator(generator=validation_generator,
steps=nb_validation_samples // batch_size)
print("Accuracy = ", scores[1])

Y_pred = model.predict_generator(validation_generator, nb_validation_samples // batch_size)

y_pred = np.argmax(Y_pred, axis=1)

print('Confusion Matrix')

print(confusion_matrix(validation_generator.classes, y_pred))

print('Classification Report')

target_names = ['Cats', 'Dogs']

print(classification_report(validation_generator.classes, y_pred, target_names=target_names))
model.save("model_tuned.h5")
```

Accuracy =  0.974375

Confusion Matrix
[[186 214]
 [199 201]]

Classification Report

```
          precision    recall  f1-score   support

    Cats       0.48      0.47      0.47       400
    Dogs       0.48      0.50      0.49       400
```

micro avg       0.48      0.48      0.48       800
   macro avg       0.48      0.48      0.48       800
weighted avg       0.48      0.48      0.48       800

Comment: I have the same problem, basically, the title of your question here is incorrect. Your training accuracy is high, but the classification report does not reflect the truth.

Answer (score 6):

I think the problem is that you should add shuffle = False in your validation generator

```
validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
validation_data_dir,
target_size=(img_height, img_width),
batch_size=batch_size,
class_mode='categorical',
shuffle=False)
```

The problem is that the default behaviour is to shuffle the images so the label order of

```
validation_generator.classes
```

doesn't match the generator

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues with your model. First you need to use softmax activation if you have more than one output neuron:

```
top_model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))
```

And then you have to use `categorical_crossentropy` loss, binary crossentropy is only for when you have one output neuron with sigmoid activations.

```
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer=optimizers.SGD(lr=1e-4, momentum=0.9),
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Comment: actually i'm confused. I have two classes, is it okay to use softmax

Comment: Yes, it is okay

Comment: I've made the changes you recommended but I still get bad predictions. are there other suggestions? I appreciate your help sir

Comment: With two classes that are mutually exclusive, you should just use 1 output neuron with a sigmoid activation function and `binary_crossentropy` loss. The softmax can actually be seen as an extension of the sigmoid when you have more than 2 classes.

Comment: @GiuseppeMarra No, a two class softmax can also be used, there is no single option as you are implying.

Answer (score 1):

I am doing skin cancer classification and the data are balanced. Now consider the confusion matrix below and its accuracy. This is still not matching and it can not be a case of data imbalance. Link

Dataset
`test_pred = model.predict(test_generator)` output is accuracy 89%
and

the confusion matrix is given by
`array([[267, 271], [233, 229]])`  
This is not anyway matching.
[1]: https://kaggle.com/hasnainjaved/melanoma-skin-cancer-dataset-of-10000-images

Answer (score 0):

There are usually two reasons for this problem:

1. The most common one is when we implement (predict) the model with a different form of image (maybe forget to normalize or mix up height and width). This does not seem to be the case here.
2. The second one is when there are many more samples of one class over the others. Say there are 1000 samples A and 100 samples B. If the model only gesses A it will be correct 90% of the time. This is called a "local minimum" in mathematics, and even if the validation result yields 0.9 accuracy, the implementation will be horrible.

In short, are you dealing with imbalanced data? It is sometimes hard to avoid local minima in this case. Could this be the issue here?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I am doing skin cancer classification and the data is balanced. Now consider the confusion matrix below and its accuracy. This is still not matching and it can not be case of data imbalance. [Link](kaggle.com/hasnainjaved/melanoma-skin-cancer-dataset-of-10000-images) Dataset `code` test_pred = model.predict(test_generator) `code` out put is 89% and confusion matrix is `code` array([[267, 271],
       [233, 229]]) `code`

Answer (score 0):

Somehow, the predict_generator() of Keras' model does not work as expected. I would rather loop through all test images one-by-one and get the prediction for each image in each iteration. I am using Plaid-ML Keras as my backend and to get prediction I am using the following code.

```
import os
from PIL import Image
import keras
import numpy

print("Prediction result:")
dir = "/path/to/test/images"
files = os.listdir(dir)
correct = 0
total = 0
#dictionary to label all traffic signs class.
classes = {
    0:'This is Cat',
    1:'This is Dog',
}
for file_name in files:
    total += 1
    image = Image.open(dir + "/" + file_name).convert('RGB')
    image = image.resize((100,100))
    image = numpy.expand_dims(image, axis=0)
    image = numpy.array(image)
    image = image/255
    pred = model.predict_classes([image])[0]
    sign = classes[pred]
    if ("cat" in file_name) and ("cat" in sign):
        print(correct,". ", file_name, sign)
        correct+=1
    elif ("dog" in file_name) and ("dog" in sign):
        print(correct,". ", file_name, sign)
        correct+=1
print("accuracy: ", (correct/total))
```